# Twitter Bootstrap Containers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, containers, html

Ive been using bootstrap for a few months and am looking to clarify something as part of best practices.

My question is do I create a container for each row or just one big container for the whole page.

Example1 (Closed Containers)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 offest2">
            <h1>Content</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 offest2">
            <h1>More Content</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example 2 (1 large container)

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 offest2">
            <h1>Content</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 offest2">
            <h1>Content</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Any help appreciated, just dont want to get into bad habits early on

Comment: I think the answer is actually Example 1. Say your design has a header that requires to be `container-fluid` + `row-fluid`, but the main content area is supposed to be fixed, then the footer needs to be fluid again. You'll probably be better off with 3 containers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend the second example.
In the first you have duplicate code wich makes no real sense. 
Always think about the principle "Don't repeat yourself".

Answer (score 16):

Multiple rows can logically be part of the same grid, like rows in a table. The .container represents one grid. So Example 2 would be the way to go.